# Can a C# object "kill" itself?

Tags: c#

In C#, can an object method invoke the object's own d-tor? and making any reference to the object invalid?

I'm trying to build an "object control" in memory system. user can "checkout" an object, then "finish" working with it ("checkin"). and I need to be sure once the object is "checked in" - any reference to it in the user code, will become invalid.

Here is an illustrated situation

```
public class MyType
{
     public object Object {get; private set;}

     public MyType()
     {
         this.Object = new ... ; // initialize Object property
     }

     public void Finish()
     {
         // ... some work on this.Object

         this.Object = null;
         // this = null;   <- kill myself ?
     }
}

pubic class Consumer()
{
   public void Method()
   {
        var myUsage = new MyType(); // underline Object is initialized

        SomethingWith(myUsage.Object); // use underline Object

        myUsage.Finish();              // complete the usage

        SomethingWith(myUsage.Object); // <-- exception, myUsage is not valid, is null or something similar
   }

   public void SomethingWith(object obj)
   {
       obj.Method(); 
       ....
   }
}
```

Comment: Given your sample code, you cannot prevent anyone stowing away a reference to the object anywhere `object stolen = myUsage.Object;` - and the GC will only dispose your objects if all references to it are removed.

Comment: If you want to "finish" your objects then this objects need to maintain that state and check in all methods if it has been finished. You may "misuse" the Dispose interface here. But still you will  need to check yourself in that object that it has been disposed/finished. There is not magic that does it for you.

Comment: Maybe you could build the logic into a factory class, that holds the object reference. Then calling the factories Finish method would set the inner object reference to null?

Comment: Consider creating some kind of Disposable `Lease` class that wraps the real objects and proxies all calls to them. When it's disposed, it returns the checked out object back to the pool/manager and all of the methods can then throw ObjectDisposedExceptions.

Comment: [WeakReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: @shingo Thought about this, too. But it doesn't help: A weak reference only becomes free when the target object is _actually_ gone. But here, it should still be kept, only not accessed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The Garbage Collector is *very* careful about not causing any leaked references. Therefore if somebody still has a reference to an object, it's not possible to prevent that he's manipulating it.

For what you need to do, you need to store the logic about accessibility within the object (or a common base class of it). So that your object can track when it's "owned" and when not. This will probably be ugly, as you have to secure all public methods as well as all properties from being accessed while the object is not owned. As an extra complexity, you need to make sure the access only happens from whoever actually owns the object and not from somebody else.

I don't know your exact use case there, but I would suggest to use proper locking within the object, so that it does not have to care about who accesses it, but it still keeps a consistent state.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually this is the approach I am taking, just wanted to check if there is a more clean way to achieve my goal...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should avoid to allow direct access to nested object: you can create a method on MyType class that internally it access to the nested object, e.g.

```
public void DoSomething(){
   if(_nestedObject!=null) {
     _nestedObject.DoSomething();
   }
}
```

As extra check, you could replace the call to Finish method with the IDisposable pattern.
You implement IDispose interface, then you use you class as belove

```
using(var wrapper =new MyType()) {
  wrapper.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible for an object to request to be killed. It would rely on the parent object to perform the task upon request.

Comment: Do you have sources to prove this statement right?